# Struts 2 Visitor Validator with OGNL expression context

Tags: validation, struts2

I'm having an issue using the "Visitor" validator in Struts 2. It works correctly if I hard-code the "context" parameter. The problem lies in the fact that I need this to be an OGNL expression.

For instance:

```
<validators>
<field name="model">
    <field-validator type="visitor">
        <param name="context">%{myAlias}</param>
        <param name="appendPrefix">false</param>
        <message />     
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

This will call the "getMyAlias" method in my action, (which it does successfully!) which returns a String.

```
public class ValidationAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<ValidationModel>{

    private ValidationModel xyz = new ValidationModel();

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {  
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationModel getModel() {
        return xyz;
    }

    public String getMyAlias(){
        return "b";
    }

}
```

I created a validation xml file named "ValidationModel-b-validation.xml" and placed it in the package with my ValidationModel.java file. Simply changing the "%{myAlias}" to "b" results in a successful validation.

So, I know that the Visitor validator works, but just not with the OGNL expression.

Any ideas why? Google has been no help at all. It seems nobody has ever tried this.

Comment: Try `<param name="context">%{getMyAlias()}</param>`?

Comment: @nmc That gives the same results as %{myAlias}. The <s:debug> tag shows the variable "choice" (my <s:select> tag variable) and "myAlias" both being set to "b", so I'm still at a loss as to why it's not visiting the model validation.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the exact same problem right now.

Comment: @MattMcHugh no, I didn't. Apparently it just doesn't work. I just implemented the validate() method and used an if to validate based on the value of a radio button.

Comment: Darn, was hoping to avoid that.  Thanks.